# Parse string that is a collection of data using MatLab

Tags: string, matlab, csv, extract

I have a collection of data in form of a string with csv that I am getting from a C# app. 
How can I make a matlab function that parses the string and creates the code below:

```
collection{1}.name                  = 'something';
collection{1}.method                = 'csv';
collection{1}.classScope            = 'set';

collection{1}.opts.samples          = 220;
collection{1}.opts.varCount         = 34;
collection{1}.opts.ignoreVars       = [1 9:10 21 25 28:34];
collection{1}.opts.startLine        = 2;

collection{1}.dataset{1}.class      = 1;
collection{1}.dataset{1}.baseDir    = 'somedir';
collection{1}.dataset{1}.name       = 'Normal';

collection{1}.dataset{2}.class      = 2;
collection{1}.dataset{2}.baseDir    = 'somedir';
collection{1}.dataset{2}.name       = 'something';

collection{1}.dataset{3}.class      = 2;
collection{1}.dataset{3}.baseDir    = 'somedir';
collection{1}.dataset{3}.name       = 'something';

collection{1}.dataset{4}.class      = 2;
collection{1}.dataset{4}.baseDir    = 'somedir';
collection{1}.dataset{4}.name       = 'something';
```

The original string will be like:

```
string = [collection{1}.name = 'something', collection{1}.method = 'csv', collection{1}.classScope = 'set', collection{1}.opts.samples = 220, collection{1}.opts.varCount = 34, ................]
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you desire.  Are you saying that you have a string stored in the variable `string`, and you want to make it create code like what you see at the beginning of your post?

Comment: splits the string using strplit(,( and then use the eval function
http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html

Comment: thanks alexandre.. your method worked.